# Binance Margin Borrow API in java

Tags: java, api, cryptocurrency, binance

I am new to Binance API and I'm having some difficulty to invoke Binance margin borrow API. I have referred their API documentation, But don't know how to invoke the margin borrow API through java. So, I would like to someone guide or share me an example code to invoke their margin API in java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far and exactly which API you are referring to a link maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The request used by [their website](https://www.binance.com/en/margin-fee) has the following curl structure:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://www.binance.com/gateway-api/v1/public/margin/vip/spec/list-all' \
--header 'content-type: application/json'
```

In Java with [apache http client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.12), you can do it like this:

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
    httpGet.setURI(new URI("https://www.binance.com/gateway-api/v1/public/margin/vip/spec/list-all"));
    httpGet.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    String responseJson = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println(responseJson);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to use the API for margin borrowing of an asset. I referred to this link -"https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#margin-account-transfer-margin".But I don't know how to implement this in java and also I don't know how to pass the API key and secret key.It would be great if you guide me through.

Comment: You should have specified that in your question

Comment: I have modified the question and if you know how to use binance margin borrow API in java,please post a sample snippet of code to guide me through

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand by a quick look at the docs, you will have to generate a `HMAC SHA256 signature` from your secretKey as the key and totalParams as the value for the HMAC operation and your API-key is passed into the Rest API via the `X-MBX-APIKEY header`.

```
    String hmac = HMAC_SHA256("secret_key", "totalParams")

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
      .uri(URI.create("api uri here"))
      .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
      .header("X-MBX-APIKEY", "api-key here")
      .POST(totalParamsHere)
      .build()
```